# in intellij idea build menu, date and time are displayed in Arabic numbers

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, settings

[enter image description here][1]**how to adjust intellij idea setting help me??**
How to fix the date and time appearing in this picture?
Please help to fix this?

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/

:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

**??????????????????????**

۲۰۲۲-۰۷-۲۹ ۰۹:۵۰:۵۴.۹۷۴  INFO 2940 ---
[           main] uz.napa.gapgapbot.GapgapBotApplication   : Starting GapgapBotApplication using Java 11.0.9 on DESKTOP-84JCKN7 with PID 2940 (D:\Asosiy JAVA\gap-Gap\gapgap-bot\target\classes started by islom in D:\Asosiy JAVA\gap-Gap\gapgap-bot)

۲۰۲۲-۰۷-۲۹ ۰۹:۵۰:۵۴.۹۷۴  INFO 2940 ---
[           main] uz.napa.gapgapbot.GapgapBotApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

۲۰۲۲-۰۷-۲۹ ۰۹:۵۰:۵۶.۱۴۶  INFO 2940 ---
[           main] uz.napa.gapgapbot.GapgapBotApplication   : Started GapgapBotApplication in 1.533 seconds (JVM running for 2.967)

Comment: It's probably getting that from the Locale settings on your computer.  I don't recall ever seeing a setting in IntelliJ or in Spring Boot for displaying dates with Persian numbers.

Comment: Please follow [ask] when posting the questions